# Remove backslash with str.translate

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I wrote the following Python2.7 code to remove digits and the backslash character (\) from some string. I attempted to use the str.translate method, because I had learned that it is very efficient. The code below successfully removed digits from the string x, but is unable to remove the single backslash in y. What did I do wrong?

```
import string    
x = 'xb7'
y = '\xb7'
print x.translate(None, '\\' + string.digits)
print y.translate(None, '\\' + string.digits)
```

Comment: `\xb7` is the hexadecimal string of B7, so there is no backslash

Comment: .. `\xb7` behaves like one character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any strings with backslashes. `x` has the characters `'x'`, `'b'`, and `'7'`, while `y` has a single character, `'·'`, denoted by the hex code `b7`. If you want the literal string `'\xb7'`, with four characters in it, use a raw string by prefixing an `r` in front of the literal.

```
>>> import string
>>> print r'\xb7'.translate(None, '\\' + string.digits)
xb
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm works much better when there's actually a backslash to remove.  Tigerhawk already showed you your hexadecimal string.  Here's another simplistic example to help, showing the unchanged original **y**.

```
import string
x = 'xb7'
y = '\\xb7'
print x, y
kill = '\\' + string.digits
print "kill", kill
print x.translate(None, kill)
print y.translate(None, kill)
print "y=", y
```

Output:

```
xb7 \xb7
kill \0123456789
xb
xb
y= \xb7
```